# Handling External Dependencies in a Factory

Tags: domain-driven-design, factory, factory-pattern

I have a factory class which i feel needs to be re factored, take the following example:

```
public class FileFactory
{
    public static FileType Create(string fileName)
    {
        if(IsImageFile(fileName))       
        {
            return new ImageFileType();
        } 
        else if(IsDocumentFile(fileName))
        {
            return new DocumentFileType();
        }
        ...
    }

    private static bool IsImageFile(string fileName)
    {
        string imageFileTypes[] = string[] {".jpg", ".gif", ".png"}; //How to avoid this line of code?
        return imageFileTypes.Contains(fileName);
    }
}
```

I'm loosely following Domain Driven Design principals and so this FileFactory class is a domain object.  Should the factory class access the repository / DB to get the file types?

How should i handle the dependency in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new, unknown image file type is really unlikely.  It's fine to hard code this.

If you're really, really intent on keeping that file list as an external dependency, pass the list of file types into the `FileFactory` constructor and make `Create()` an instance method instead of static.  That'll keep you testable and SOLID.